# How to build the simplest multi module Maven project using Windows command line?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have multi module project which is **very simple**.

Directory structure:

```
   C:\acme-project\parent
   C:\acme-project\alpha   
   C:\acme-project\beta
```

Logical structure:

```
     parent
    /     \
 alpha <- beta
```

I cannot build the `beta` because it depends on the `alpha`. And Meven **doesn't want to build the alpha** during the beta's build process!

```
C:\acme-project\beta> mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building beta 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.company:alpha:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.263 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T15:00:34+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project beta: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:beta:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.company:alpha:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.company:alpha:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

My POMs :

C:\acme-project\parent\parent.pom :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>../alpha</module>
    <module>../beta</module>    
  </modules>
</project>
```

C:\acme-project\alpha\alpha.com :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>alpha</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

C:\acme-project\beta\beta.pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>beta</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>alpha</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I can build the acme-project running `mvn package` in C:...\parent. But in case of more complex project `parent` could have 100 sub-modules. And obviously I don't want to build 98 modules (others that `beta` doesn't depend on) just to make Maven happy.

Comment: In a multi-module project, you usually build the parent, which builds all modules. If you don't want that (and the modules do not depend on each other), you probably do not want to have a multi-module project.

Comment: Why I cannot build just one module? It's simply silly.

Comment: It's also not necessary these days to flatten your project structure. Your poms will be even simpler if you use the natural directory hierarchy.

Comment: @ieXcept Maybe you can, but why do you want to group unrelated projects in a multi-module project?

Comment: @JFMeier Suppose, there are `core-module`, `model`, `web-services`, `persistence`, `console-client`, `desktop-client`, `android-cl ... etc. All clients and web-services must share some modules, e.g. `model`. But when I am working only on `desktop-client` I don't want to build `android-client`.

Comment: @SteveC Could you please give me some hints why other projects use this inconvenience flattened project structure? And what is a disadvantage to follow hierarchical directory structure when `parent` directory contains its submodules?

Comment: @ieXcept You can use separate projects and use standard Maven dependencies. You need not put everything into one project. You can even trigger dependent builds if you want using Jenkins or another build server.

Comment: @ieXcept, other projects did it this way because in the olden days Eclipse was unable to deal with nested projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build just the projects that `beta` depends on, go to the root aggregator (i.e., the project with all the `<modules>`; `parent` in your case) and then ask Maven to build only `beta` **and** its dependencies in the current reactor:

```
cd parent
mvn package --projects com.company:beta --also-make
```

FYI, this can be abbreviated:

```
mvn package -pl :beta -am
```

In your minimal example, the above command will still build everything (as `beta` depends on `alpha` and implicitly on the `parent`), but in larger reactors it will build just the minimal subset necessary to build `beta`.

Comment: It really works. These arguments forces maven to build only module (and its dependencies only) that I need. Thank you!